# Non-zero exit status on attempt in installing 'jr' and 'jr.gd' packages; cannot find 'config.log'

Tags: java, r, linux, eclipse, debian

I'm trying to install the `rj` and `rj.gd` packages. I apologise for including the whole output, but that's so information regarding my R installation and version can be seen properly. I get a non-zero exiting status when running `install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="https://download.walware.de/rj-4.0")`, as can be seen below.

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="https://download.walware.de/rj-4.0")
Installing packages into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://download.walware.de/rj-4.0/src/contrib/rj_4.0.5-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 359978 bytes (351 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 351 KB

trying URL 'https://download.walware.de/rj-4.0/src/contrib/rj.gd_4.0.5-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 105189 bytes (102 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 102 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rj’ ...
** using staged installation
checking R config... R config set
    R_HOME   : /usr/lib/R
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking Java support in R... ...
11.0.14
Java config set
    JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
    JAVA     : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
    JAVAC    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
    JAVAC_FLAGS:  -h .
    JAVA_CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux
    JAVA_LIBS: -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm
    JAR      : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
=== configuring in jri (/tmp/RtmpUDmugm/R.INSTALL31f56406521ac/rj/jri)
configure: running /bin/bash ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking R config... checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.
configure: error: ./configure failed for jri
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rj’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rj’
ERROR: dependency ‘rj’ is not available for package ‘rj.gd’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rj.gd’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpMjzas9/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos = "https://download.walware.de/rj-4.0") :
  installation of package ‘rj’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos = "https://download.walware.de/rj-4.0") :
  installation of package ‘rj.gd’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't know where `config.log` is, and I couldn't find that via the few search engines I tried. JNI is Java Native Interface, right? Should I reinstall Java and see? What's the proper way of doing this without messing up my Eclipse installation? I heard that this could be a 32bit vs 64bit problem, but hitting `java --version` returns this:

```
openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

As far as I know, this means that my Java is 64bit.

P.S. I'm not a Java guy. I'm just an amateur slowly learning C and R, for now.

Comment: You might have to configure R to find your JRE. `R CMD javareconf`, maybe? Or set `JAVA_HOME` and `R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.R/Makevars`? See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Java-support). (Just guessing - I've never had to install a Java-using package.)

Comment: @Mikael Jagan This is the output I get: https://pastebin.com/QLSs0QiN I think I can manage to find my Java library path, etc. with the help of a search engine, but how do I then specify those in the R console? Thanks for your response; it's very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `rJava` is another Java-using package and there seem to be a number of threads here about how to install it on Linux. Following one of those might help.